# Mysql Error #1064 near Null in call stored procedure with out param

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-error-1064

I'm quite new with MySQL. I have to call a stored procedure with output param. I've searched a lot on internet but I've not found the correct solution to my problem. If I call the stored procedure with the @outputParamName it says that I  have an error #1064 near NULL. If I call the procedure with the 'outputParamName' without the @ it says thath it is not an OUT or INOUT correct param. Someone can help me please? 
 the stored procedure just have to check if surname and name in DB exists on the same row:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertProc (INOUT existsInDb BOOLEAN, 
                         IN dbName VARCHAR(50)
                         IN tableName VARCHAR(50)
                         IN surnameNew VARCHAR(50)
                         IN nameNew VARCHAR(50))
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
BEGIN
 DECLARE rowSurnameName int;
 SET @sqlSel = CONCAT('SELECT COUNT(*) INTO ', rowSurnameName, ' FROM ', dbName, '.', tableName, ' WHERE COGNOME=', surnameNew, ' AND NOME=', nameNew); 
 PREPARE stmtSel FROM @sqlSel; 
 EXECUTE stmtSel; 
 DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmtSel; 
 IF (rowSurnameName=0) THEN 
   SET @sqlIns = CONCAT('INSERT INTO ', dbName, '.', tableName, ' (NOME, COGNOME) VALUES (', nameNew, ', ', surnameNew,')'); 
   PREPARE stmtIns FROM @sqlIns; 
   EXECUTE stmtIns; 
   DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmtIns; 
   SELECT false INTO existsInDb; 
 ELSE SELECT true INTO existsInDb; 
 END IF; 
END
```

The CALL Statement is:

```
SET @dbName = 'DBNAME';
SET @tableName = 'DBTABLE';
SET @surname = 'SURNAME';
SET @name = 'NAME';

PREPARE s FROM 'CALL InsertProc(?,?,?,?,?)';
EXECUTE s USING @existsInDB, @dbName, @tableName, @surname, @name;
SELECT @existsInDB;
```

And the ERROR Line is:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1
```

Comment: You are probably missing the delimiter from the create procedure. Also, your prepared statements do not seem to be ok either.

Comment: Furthermore, you have lot more parameters in the prepared statement when you call the stored proc, than in the stored proc's definition.

Comment: You're right... I forgot to delete some parameters, but the problem is not in the number of parameters. In the question I put less parameters because the problem was relative to the output variable.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of notes:

- You can't use a local variable in a prepared statement.

  > [C.1 Restrictions on Stored Programs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-program-restrictions.html)
  >
  > ...
  >
  > SELECT ... INTO local_var cannot be used as a prepared statement.
  >
  > ...

  The error shown in your question occurs because the local variable `rowSurnameName` has the value `NULL`, see:

  > ```
  > mysql> DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `InsertProc`;
  > Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
  >
  > mysql> DELIMITER //
  >
  > mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE `InsertProc`()
  >     -> BEGIN
  >     ->   DECLARE `rowSurnameName` INT;
  >     ->   SELECT `rowSurnameName`;
  >     ->   SET @`sqlSel` := CONCAT('SELECT COUNT(*) INTO ',  `rowSurnameName`);
  >     ->   SELECT @`sqlSel`;
  >     -> END//
  > Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
  >
  > mysql> DELIMITER ;
  >
  > mysql> CALL `InsertProc`;
  > +------------------+
  > | `rowSurnameName` |
  > +------------------+
  > |             NULL |
  > +------------------+
  > 1 row in set (0.00 sec)
  >
  > +-----------+
  > | @`sqlSel` |
  > +-----------+
  > | NULL      |
  > +-----------+
  > 1 row in set (0.00 sec)
  >
  > Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
  > ```

  If you try to use the `rowSurnameName` local variable in the prepared statement, you will get the error:

  > ```
  > mysql> DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `InsertProc`;
  > Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
  >
  > mysql> DELIMITER //
  >
  > mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE `InsertProc`()
  >     -> BEGIN
  >     ->   DECLARE `rowSurnameName` INT;
  >     ->   SET @`sqlSel` := CONCAT('SELECT 100 INTO `rowSurnameName`');
  >     ->   SELECT @`sqlSel`;
  >     ->   PREPARE `stmtSel` FROM @`sqlSel`;
  >     ->   EXECUTE `stmtSel`;
  >     ->   DEALLOCATE PREPARE `stmtSel`;
  >     -> END//
  > Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
  >
  > mysql> DELIMITER ;
  >
  > mysql> CALL `InsertProc`;
  > +----------------------------------+
  > | @`sqlSel`                        |
  > +----------------------------------+
  > | SELECT 100 INTO `rowSurnameName` |
  > +----------------------------------+
  > 1 row in set (0.00 sec)
  >
  > ERROR 1327 (42000): Undeclared variable: rowSurnameName
  > ```
- You need to use [9.4 User-Defined Variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html) in your prepared statement:

  > ```
  > mysql> DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `InsertProc`;
  > Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
  >
  > mysql> DELIMITER //
  >
  > mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE `InsertProc`()
  >     -> BEGIN
  >     ->   SET @`sqlSel` := CONCAT('SELECT 100 INTO @`rowSurnameName`');
  >     ->   SELECT @`sqlSel`;
  >     ->   PREPARE `stmtSel` FROM @`sqlSel`;
  >     ->   EXECUTE `stmtSel`;
  >     ->   DEALLOCATE PREPARE `stmtSel`;
  >     ->   IF (@`rowSurnameName` = 0) THEN
  >     ->     SELECT 'NotExistsInDbAndInsert';
  >     ->   ELSE
  >     ->     SELECT 'existsInDb';
  >     ->   END IF;
  >     -> END//
  > Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
  >
  > mysql> DELIMITER ;
  >
  > mysql> CALL `InsertProc`;
  > +-----------------------------------+
  > | @`sqlSel`                         |
  > +-----------------------------------+
  > | SELECT 100 INTO @`rowSurnameName` |
  > +-----------------------------------+
  > 1 row in set (0.00 sec)
  >
  > +------------+
  > | existsInDb |
  > +------------+
  > | existsInDb |
  > +------------+
  > 1 row in set (0.00 sec)
  >
  > Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
  > ```